# JSON dynamic property name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a json data like below with the same Image structure and different color names.

```
     {    
      "colorImages":{
    "Giraffe-safari Sand": [
      {
        "large": "...jpg",
        "thumb": "...jpg",
        "hiRes": "...jpg",        
        "main": {
          "...jpg": [ "862", "679" ],
          "...jpg": [ "434", "342" ],
          "...jpg": [ "663", "522" ]         
        }
      },
      {
        "large": "...jpg",
        "thumb": "...jpg",
        "hiRes": "...jpg",       
        "main": {
          "...jpg": [ "606", "398" ],
          "...jpg": [ "500", "328" ]          
        }
      }],
      "Pawprint - Burgundy": [
      {
        "large": "...jpg",
        "thumb": "...jpg",
        "hiRes": "...jpg",        
        "main": {
          "...jpg": [ "862", "679" ],
          "...jpg": [ "434", "342" ],
          "...jpg": [ "663", "522" ]         
        }
      },
      {
        "large": "...jpg",
        "thumb": "...jpg",
        "hiRes": "...jpg",       
        "main": {
          "...jpg": [ "606", "398" ],
          "...jpg": [ "500", "328" ]          
        }
      }]
  }
}
```

My model class:

```
public partial class Aa
{
    [JsonProperty("colorImages")]
    public Images ColorImages { get; set; }
}

public partial class Images
{
   [JsonProperty("Giraffe-safari Sand")]
    public List<ImageItem> GiraffeSafariSand { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Pawprint - Burgundy")]
    public List<ImageItem> PawprintBurgundy { get; set; }
}
public partial class ImageItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("large")]
        public Uri Large { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thumb")]
        public Uri Thumb { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hiRes")]
        public Uri HiRes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("variant")]
        public string Variant { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("main")]
        public Dictionary<string, List<long>> Main { get; set; }
    }
```

How can I use Jsonconverter for dynamic property name so that I dont need to repeat [JsonProperty("Giraffe-safari Sand")] and [JsonProperty("Pawprint - Burgundy")] because there will be thousands of color name to handle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `JSonConvert` method from `Microsoft.Json`. Edit your object like this.

```
public class Aa
    {
        [JsonProperty("colorImages")]
        public Dictionary<string, List<ImageItem>> Images { get; set; }
    }
    public class ImageItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("large")]
        public Uri Large { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("thumb")]
        public Uri Thumb { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hiRes")]
        public Uri HiRes { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("variant")]
        public string Variant { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("main")]
        public Dictionary<string, List<long>> Main { get; set; }
    }
```

And in you conversion code :

```
var deserializedSrc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Aa>(src);
```

You will have a dictionary which keys will be `Giraffe-safari Sand`, `Pawprint - Burgundy` etc.

Answer (score 0):

To make a custom, dynamic item name and value(s), you can use a Dictionary:

```cs
[JsonProperty("Images")]
public Dictionary<string, List<ImageItem>> Images { get; set; }
```